# How to set the value to the first N elements of a list?

Tags: c#, linq

Given a list I want to set a value (in my case the red color) to the first 3 elements; the rest of the elements will have another color

I have this so far

```
int top3=0;
foreach (MyCustomObject gb in Data)
{
    if (top3 <= 3)
    {
        gb.NodeColor = Colors.Green;
    }
    else
    {
        gb.NodeColor = Colors.Red;
    }
    top3++;
}
```

I don't like this approach, Is there a way to do this with LINQ?

Fyi my list is ordered ascending and MyCustomObject is not the real name of my class

Comment: This is not a job for LINQ.

Comment: Yes when you do everything with linq, it is better :)

Comment: @L.B No. LINQ is not a master of all trades. It is awesome at a lot, but this is not one.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. See the last `:)` in my comment.

Comment: @L.B Is it the new sarcmark?

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Yes, with the context of the sentence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why not just a regular `for` loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < Data.Count(); i++ )
{
    Data[i].NodeColor = (i < 3 ? Colors.Red : Colors.Green);
}
```

I personally think that is more readable than it would be in LINQ, but as always, your mileage may vary.

Comment: I think OP wanted `i <= 3`, rather than `i < 3`; otherwise great answer, though.

Comment: @rae1n first three will be 0,1,2

Comment: @rae1n <= wouldn't make sense, though. He said "the first 3 elements", so <= would be four elements, 0,1,2,3.

Comment: I know, however, if you look at the question, the code actually has `int top3 = 0; ... if (top3 <= 3)`... not sure what the OP actually wants or whether the second part is a mistake.

Comment: Hmm, yes, his original question was a bit ambiguous in whether he wants 3 or 4, wasn't it? He stated 3, but his code takes 4. Well, either way, the answer should be easy to adapt.

Comment: He also said he wants to set red to the first three, but the code sets green to the first three. It is a mystery!

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like this maybe? Not much cleaner...

```
    for (int i = 0; i < elementsToSet; i++)
       array[i].NodeColor = Colors.Green;

    for (elementsToSet; elementsToSet < array.Length; elementsToSet++)
       array[elementsToSet].NodeColor = Colors.Red;
```

Edit: Just noticed you wanted LINQ... Woops

Comment: As much as this isn't LINQ as OP asked, it is the best option.

Answer (score 2):

While I would normally use two `for` loops for this, as was mentioned in an earlier answer, you can use a bit of LINQ if you *really* want to throw some in there:

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 3))
    Data[i].NodeColor = Colors.Green;
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(3, Data.Length - 3))
    Data[i].NodeColor = Colors.Red;
```

Comment: Why would you do that? This seems to me just a way to make code more confusing.

Comment: @FabioMarcolini As I said; I'd personally use a `for` loop.  The question specifically asks to use LINQ, and this uses it while not really cause problems, even if it's not really adding much either.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it using the an overload of the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension method:

```
var result = Data.Select((x, index) => {
        x.NodeColor = index < 3 ? Colors.Red : Colors.Green;
        return x;
    }).ToArray();
```

However, it is up to you whether this is really better than a plain loop as it obfuscates the fact that the values of the input data are changed in the selector function. So cloning the data might be a better approach in the selector function.

Comment: The only problem is that it will *never* get executed because of *deferred execution* unless you use ToList or ToArray.

Answer (score 0):

You could do,

```
int top3 = 3; // Although I think you actually want top4 based on 'i <= 3'
Data.Take(top3).ToList().ForEach(gb => gb.NodeColor = Colors.Green);
Data.Skip(top3).ToList().ForEach(gb => gb.NodeColor = Colors.Red);
```

Although in this case you might end up traversing the `Data` source twice; might be better to just use a `for` as @Charlie Kilian mentions.

Comment: And Data will still be the original values. So this still gets us nowhere.

Comment: @PatrickMagee That's not true. Modifying the value of an instance's property does affect the items in the original collection, i.e. `Data`. I'll agree it might inefficient/overkill, but this code does what the OP requested.

Comment: @PatrickMagee You are using *value* types. Value types get copied. `Data` is a reference type and only the reference is copied. Therefore, this answer is correct. Try your sample with a class and a property.

Comment: You can not modify an Enumerable collection. you will have to set the original back to new list of data. Enumerable only exposes an Enumerator.

Comment: @PatrickMagee You are reassigning *the reference*. Try with a class and a property.

Comment: That example refers to a list of value types. Do the same with a list of reference types (like the one in the question) and you'll understand what I'm saying. In your example calling to `ToList` on `IEnumerable<int>` or `IEnumerable<string>` actually copies all the elements themselves into a list. When calling `ToList` on a list of reference types however, like `List<MyCustomObject>`, it copies a reference to the same set of objects in memory, which have the same properties, thus why it works.

Answer (score -1):

Due to the fact IEnumerable doesn't have ForEach extension may be it's better to go with for loop for instance. But if you really need LINQ than you need to implement an extension for IEnumerable

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                                      Action<T> action){
        foreach (var e in source){
            action(e);
            yield return e;
        }
    }
```

than you can use it in next way

```
Data.Take(4).ForEach(data=>data.Color=Colors.Red);
Data.Skip(4).ForEach(data=>data.Color=Colors.Green);
```

Comment: This is not LINQ and should not be called/used as such. Also, with the behaviour shown in the title it should be Take(4)/Skip(4).

Comment: but take  will return  a new array of three elements

Comment: The question didn't mention if it was IEnumerable. The question said it was a List and a ForEach works on a List. All you need is System.Linq. Why are people down voting?

Comment: @Artiom Take+Skip return IEnumerable

Comment: @Artiom I say. See my previous comment

Comment: Artiom, only problem is, you have now modified the contents of the List from ToList(), not the original data. But i see what you were attemting.

Comment: my project has an extension for IEnumerable<T>. That's why I've put in the answer

Comment: @PatrickMagee You still miss the point. Assuming `MyCustomObject` is a class, it does now what OP asks. But it is not what linq is suitable for. SO I won't cancel my downvote,